# Google OAuth2 Javascript client not working mobile

Tags: mobile, google-authentication, google-api-js-client

I'm writing a web app that needs to send an email from the user to a system admin. To do this I'm using google's Gmail api. This needs authorization. The following snippet successfully authorizes when using a desktop, but fails on mobile.

```
this.sendEmail = function(to, body, attachments, callback) {

    _to = to;
    _body = body;
    _attachments = [attachments];
    _callback = callback;

    gapi.client.setApiKey('MY_API_KEY');
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1').then(_authorize);
}

function _authorize(){

    var config = {
        'client_id': MY_CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    }; 

    gapi.auth.authorize(config, _sendEmail);
}

function _sendEmail(){
// code to actually send my email
}
```

on mobile, it pops up a new tab and prompts the user to log in, then nothing. it never hits my "_sendEmail" callback. If the user was already logged in it just pops up a blank window (it still never hits the callback).

If i add "immediate:true" to the config object then it goes through on mobile if the user is already signed into their google account, but fails if they're not.

Am I doing something wrong or does this just not work very well on mobile?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "on mobile", do you mean Android? iOS? Something else? Also, what browser?